# Get nearby locations from Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an app which allows users to add places of interest to a map via their Android device. They fill out name, address, phone number, etc...
I would like to automate this, or use pre-existing functionality.

So I am familiar with the Facebook app, how the user checks-in and the check-in screen displays a list of nearby places. I want to tap into this.

From my research, I've to use the Graph API. Specifically this:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/location

So on that link, the sample Android code is as follows:
Code:

```
/* make the API call */
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "...?fields={fieldname_of_type_Location}",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

That's about as far as I've gotten, and hit a dead end. Mainly because I don't know what fields to add in. I also haven't found any samples online, which makes me think I'm on the wrong track.

Does anyone know where I can get a good sample for what I'm trying to do? Or cam someone provide me with the rest missing part?
Basically I want to provide my users current location, and have Facebook provide the places nearby. On return, I want to populate some text fields.

Thanks.

EDIT: It seems all I need is the Android equivalent of this:

```
GET graph.facebook.com
  /search?
    q=coffee&
    type=place&
    center=37.76,-122.427&
    distance=1000
```

I found that sample code here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.5

I notice its searching for `coffee` but I just want to get everything within the `distance` of the coords. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I did find an Android equivalent answer. It's not very simple, and requires a lot of extra files etc.

The Facebook Github account has a sample app called Scrumptious.
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/001984c85bbb5ccb7a3df4e33fe3090d22a8ac88/samples/Scrumptious/src/com/example/scrumptious

In that sample, it uses a `PickerActivity` for picking friends or places. I'm only using the Places Picker functionality. I haven't quite got it working, and there's a few bits missing so can't post my own code, but basically I copy and pasted from that sample.

Comment: That is not an "Android equivalent". You Need to understand that the Android SDK uses Graph API calls as well. That is what I pointed out in my answer. Basically, you're not answering your question.

Answer (score -1):

There's no "Android equivalent" of the Graph API call. You can run the call straight ahead as described at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/GraphRequest/

You can use `q=*`, which should result in a query like this:

```
GET graph.facebook.com
  /search?
    q=*&
    type=place&
    center=37.76,-122.427&
    distance=1000
```